# XUnit Tests No Longer Working After Upgrade From .NET 5 To .NET 6 (Q & A)

Tags: xunit, .net-6.0

I have an xUnit unit testing project. All was working fine in .NET 5.

In Visual Studio 2022, I changed the .NET Version in the csproj to .NET 6 as shown below.

[image]

Following this, the tests build but no longer run.

There is no info in the output window. The Test Explorer just says it wont run the tests, with 'unexpected error detected'.

[image]

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: xUnit works just fine. Make sure you upgrade to the latest packages for both xUnit and Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk. You need to upgrade the Test SDK every time the *runner*, in this case Visual Studio, is upgraded. You'd run into the same problem if you kept working with .NET 5 in Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a new project and compared the `csproj` file with my old project. There were a couple of differences

First, I needed to add the nuget package for `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` (in my case, version 16.11.0). This seemed to fix it.

I also noticed a couple of properties in the first `PropertyGroup` that I was missing. I added those too. However, just adding `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` fixed it for me.

[image]

Comment: `Nullable` and `IsPackable` have nothing to do with testing. `Nullable` enables null checking during compilation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was changing from NUnit to XUnit and also needed to add the xunit.runner.visualstudio nuget package